# MongoDB installation needed to work with pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am continuing a project on a raspberry PI. Theres a lot of data generated and i want to save it now in a mongoDB Database. I have set up a database already in the network and I can connect to it on my laptop with MongoDB Compass.

Because the hardware of the Pi ist very hard to access I work over Remotecontrol - I have no connection to the Internet on the PI.

So, I am on the PI pymongo is installed - I dont know if mongoDB is installed, is that necessary to push data to a database via pymongo?

I simply try to receive the status of the server of the database with

```
client = MongoClient('myIP', 27017)
db = client['pymongo_test']
serverStatusResult = db.command("serverStatus")
print(serverStatusResult)
```

I receive an error that it timed out and I am trying to identify the problem now.. I also have forwarded the problem to the network admin that he can check if the problem is on his side and not related to pymongo..

```
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 214, in select_server
  address))
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 189, in select_servers
  self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: myIP:27017: timed out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to configure mongodb to be able to access from remote Pc or from another computer in a network. if you haven't done that please refer the link below, it will give you an idea how to configure mongodb (the documentation is for ubuntu).

https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/

if you have already configured mongodb to be able to access from all IP's make sure the port 27017 is open on server/Raspberry Pi. To allow specific port on ubuntu please refer below link

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04